# In Python3/tkinter how to intercept when the user clicks the close button on a Toplevel window

Tags: python-3.x, oop, user-interface, tkinter

I want to have one main window and one or more `Toplevel()` windows that may be opened on demand. I am able to create the windows and even to destroy them.

However, I am trying to implement a button in the main window that both opens and closes the second window (that second window should be always unique, i.e. never open twice at the same time). This is what I have now, after fiddling a little:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font


class baseApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding="5 8 5 5")

        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


class App(baseApp):
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="One",command=self.button_one)
        self.btn_remessas = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="Open/close Toplevel window",command=self.create_window1)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.btn_remessas.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def create_window1(self):
        if current_state.window2_open == False:
            self.newWindow2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.newWindow2.geometry('600x500+680+0')
            self.newWindow2.title('Second window')
            self.janela_remessas = SecondWindow(self.newWindow2)
            current_state.window2_open = True              
        else:
            self.newWindow2.destroy()
            root.update_idletasks()
            current_state.window2_open = False

    def button_one(self):
        print("button 1 pressed")


class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        #super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding="5 8 5 5")
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="button",command=self.button_function)
        self.button1.pack()                
        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def button_function(self, *event):
        print("user just pressed button")

    def close_window(self, *event): #Please fix me!
        current_state.window2_open = False
        self.destroy()


class AppStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window2_open = False  


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = App(root) 
    current_state = AppStatus()
    root.configure(background='grey95')
    root.title('Application window')
    root.geometry('1000x760+0+0')
    root.bind_all("<Mod2-q>", exit)
    root.mainloop()
```

Right now, if the user clicks the close window button, or the corresponding keyboard shortcut, the app will not know that the second window does not exist anymore, so when we press the button to open/close the window, nothing happens. Also, if we keep pressing the open/close button, there are some times when the button does not open the second window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the `wm_protocol` method of the toplevel widget. Specifically with the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol.

```
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> dlg = tk.Toplevel(root)
>>> dlg.wm_title("dialog")
''
>>> root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print("close root"))
''
>>> dlg.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print("close dialog"))
''
>>> root.mainloop()
close dialog
close root
```

The last lines are output when I click the window frame close button (the big red X). This now doesn't exit when I click this and is also called for `Alt-F4` on either of the Tk windows.

The [Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M58) has more to say. The python documentation I found seemed rather sparse.

Comment: That only seems to work for the main (root) window. It would allow to get a comfirmation dialog before quitting the application, for instance. But I am not being able to call some method or function when the user closes the second window. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The same technique works for any toplevel widget. You have to call `wm_protocol` for each toplevel though. The root toplevel doesn't catch the message for a different dialog window.

Comment: What would be the syntax to call it for each toplevel? When I add it like `self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print("oww"))`, i get an error saying that the object does not have that attribute...

Comment: added an extended example.

Comment: Ok, I think now I get it! I was placing the call to `.wm_protocol()` in the wrong place. I must be placed in the method create_window1(), like this: `            self.newWindow2.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: print("close dialog"))`. Now I just got to write a proper method to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the full working code after following the advice from patthoyts.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font


class baseApp(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.master = master

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding="5 8 5 5")

        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


class App(baseApp):
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="One",command=self.button_one)
        self.btn_remessas = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="Open/close Toplevel window",command=self.create_window2)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.btn_remessas.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def create_window2(self):
        if current_state.window2_open == False:
            self.newWindow2 = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
            self.newWindow2.geometry('600x500+680+0')
            self.newWindow2.title('Second window')
            self.janela_remessas = SecondWindow(self.newWindow2)
            current_state.window2_open = True
            self.newWindow2.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.close_window2())        
        else:
            self.close_window2()

    def close_window2(self, *event):
        print("closing window")
        root.update_idletasks()
        current_state.window2_open = False
        self.newWindow2.destroy()

    def button_one(self):
        print("button 1 pressed")


class SecondWindow:
    def __init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs):
        #super().__init__(master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding="5 8 5 5")
        self.topframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe)
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.topframe,text="button",command=self.button_function)
        self.button1.pack()                
        self.topframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
        self.mainframe.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def button_function(self, *event):
        print("user just pressed button")

    def close_window(self, *event): #Please fix me!
        current_state.window2_open = False
        self.destroy()


class AppStatus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window2_open = False  


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = App(root) 
    current_state = AppStatus()
    root.configure(background='grey95')
    root.title('Application window')
    root.geometry('1000x760+0+0')
    root.bind_all("<Mod2-q>", exit)
    root.mainloop()
```